# How to export sql data to xml that includes an xml schema?

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to export sql data as xml file with schema. The following code i create was able to export it as a xml file without a specific schema. What should i change in order to include an xml schema i want ? Thank you

```
 private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                sqlCon.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter("ViewAll", sqlCon);
                sqlDa.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                sqlDa.Fill(ds, "userTB");
                ds.WriteXml(@"C:\folder\phonebookDA.xml");
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only works with the overload `WriteXml(XmlWriter, XmlWriteMode)`.

As per the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset.writexml?view=netframework-4.8)

> [...] To write the schema, set the value for the `mode` parameter to `WriteSchema`.