# Export SQL Server data to XML as per XML schema file

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, ssis, xsd

I have a `.XSD` (XML Schema file) with multiple elements and attributes and I have a SQL Server table with all the columns from the `.XSD` file. How to export the data from the SQL Server table to a XML file having same formatting as the `.XSD` file (having the same elements and attributes hierarchy as the xsd file)?

For e.g. if I load the xsd file in Visual Studio, then it generates a sample XML file from the `Root` element. I want the data from the SQL Server table to be the same way as the sample XML file.

I have tried using Script Task in SSIS to write SQL data to XML with `XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema` but this generates a XML file with the default table schema and data. I only want the SQL Server data in the schema format.

My question is similar to this post [How to export sql data to xml that includes an xml schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57620227/how-to-export-sql-data-to-xml-that-includes-an-xml-schema) but the answer doesn't provide the solution I need.

Comment: Use the following query : SELECT *
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS CO
 WHERE CO.TABLE_CATALOG = 'YOUR DATABASE'
 ORDER BY TABLE_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION

Answer (score 0):

Few steps to follow:

1. SQL Server has a built-in XQuery language support. You can use
   XQuery to compose XML. And package it as a stored procedure (SP).
2. Call bcp.exe process that will be calling the SP from the step #1 above in
   SSIS to output an XML file on the file system.
3. Validate output XML file against the XSD via SSIS **XML Task**, operation Validation.

**SSIS Script Task**

```
void Main()
{
    string exeName = @"c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\bcp.exe";
    string outputFileName = @"e:\Temp\SampleXMLOutput.xml";
    string spName = "databaseName.dbo.usp_myStoredProcedure";
    string serverName = "serverName";
    string tcpPort = "1433";

    string sql = string.Format("EXEC {0};"
        , spName);

    // Create args string
    string args = string.Format("\"{0}\" queryout \"{1}\" -T -x -c -C 1252 -a 32768 -S {2},{3}"
        , sql
        , outputFileName
        , serverName
        , tcpPort);

    // Don't forget to tick/check off System::TaskName variable as ReadOnly in the Task Parameters
    Dts.Events.FireInformation(99, Dts.Variables["System::TaskName"].Value.ToString()
                      , string.Format("bcp arguments: {0}", args), "", 0, ref b);
    try
    {
        // Create new ProcessStartInfo with vars from above
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
        psi.FileName = exeName;
        psi.Arguments = args;
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
        psi.ErrorDialog = false;

        using (Process process = Process.Start(psi))
        {
            // Capture StdOut and StdErr into variables
            string vStdOutput = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            string vStdError = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

            // Wait for exit
            process.WaitForExit();
            
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(vStdOutput))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(vStdOutput);
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(vStdError))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(vStdError);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("XML file generation process completed. Exit code: {0}", process.ExitCode));
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("File '{0}' has been created.", outputFileName));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the steps. Can you please explain how to call sp in execute process task. Struggling a bit with that. Thank you!

Comment: I added SSIS Script Task implementation to launch step #2. You can replace all `Console.WriteLine(...);` calls with calls to log it to SSIS logs as I showed for the bcp arguments.